# Return results of DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS in Oracle 11

Tags: oracle

Database: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0

I would like to create a script that will return the results of the DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS function to my c# application.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
DECLARE
    refCur sys_refcursor;
    colCount number;
    descTable dbms_sql.desc_tab;

FUNCTION get_ups(foo number) RETURN sys.dbms_sql.desc_tab PIPELINED AS

    BEGIN
    OPEN refCur FOR 
    SELECT * FROM MYOWNER.MYTABLE;

    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(
        dbms_sql.to_cursor_number(refCur),
        colCount,
        descTable);

    FOR i IN 1 .. colCount LOOP
    PIPE ROW ( null );--descTable(i) );
    END LOOP;

        RETURN;
    END get_ups;

BEGIN

  SELECT *
  FROM table(get_ups(0));
END;
```

Here are my constraints:

1. I do not have create permissions on the database.
2. I need to be able to describe arbitrary queries, not just tables.
3. I'd like to consume the result as a dataset in C#. (It's for an ETL tool.)